# Bibliography with one entry bold

Tags: bibliographies, bibunits

I have a latex beamer class and in there I use the `bibunits` package to show some chosen entries of my `biblio.bib` on a specific slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{bibunits}  
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
\defaultbibliography{biblio}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some entries}
    \begin{bibunit}
      \nocite{Yang2007, Goldlucke2014, Li2014}
      \putbib
    \end{bibunit}
    and many more...
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have, let's say, the first entry bold, but only as some kind of overlay. Meaning that the first time I show this slide all entries are shown with like in the example, and on the "next" slide (with `\onslide` or something) `Yang2007` should be printed in bold. This way it is easier for audience to follow about which entry your talking at the moment.

For Completeness, here my `biblio.bib`:

```
@article{Goldlucke2014,
  title={A super-resolution framework for high-accuracy multiview reconstruction},
  author={Goldl{\"u}cke, Bastian and Aubry, Mathieu and Kolev, Kalin and Cremers, Daniel},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Vision},
  volume={106},
  number={2},
  pages={172--191},
  year={2014},
}

@inproceedings{Li2014,
  title={Similarity-aware patchwork assembly for depth image super-resolution},
  author={Li, Jing and Lu, Zhichao and Zeng, Gang and Gan, Rui and Zha, Hongbin},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  pages={3374--3381},
  year={2014}
}
@inproceedings{Yang2007,
  title={Spatial-depth super resolution for range images},
  author={Yang, Qingxiong and Yang, Ruigang and Davis, James and Nist{\'e}r, David},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  year={2007},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Goldlucke2014,
  title={A super-resolution framework for high-accuracy multiview reconstruction},
  author={Goldl{\"u}cke, Bastian and Aubry, Mathieu and Kolev, Kalin and Cremers, Daniel},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Vision},
  volume={106},
  number={2},
  pages={172--191},
  year={2014},
}

@inproceedings{Li2014,
  title={Similarity-aware patchwork assembly for depth image super-resolution},
  author={Li, Jing and Lu, Zhichao and Zeng, Gang and Gan, Rui and Zha, Hongbin},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  pages={3374--3381},
  year={2014}
}
@inproceedings{Yang2007,
  title={Spatial-depth super resolution for range images},
  author={Yang, Qingxiong and Yang, Ruigang and Davis, James and Nist{\'e}r, David},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
  year={2007\normalfont},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{bibunits}  
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
\defaultbibliography{\jobname}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\newcommand{\BIBdecl}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some entries}
    \begin{bibunit}
      \nocite{Yang2007, Goldlucke2014, Li2014}
      \putbib
    \end{bibunit}
    and many more...
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]